# SMTP Connection

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am trying to send mail via smtp but i am unable to do so. it is giving me connection error

```
 { Error: connect EACCES xx.xxx.xx.xx:25
 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
  errno: 'EACCES',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xx.xxx.xx.xx',
  port: 25,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

While the configuration i am passing are correct as same configurations has been passed in another project by me are working.

These 2 project may be on different server thought can you please guide me with the same.. i m stuck from 2 days

Here is Config For reference

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport( {
            debug: true,
            host: "smtp.xx.xxx.com",
            port: 25,
            secure: false,
            auth: {
                user: 'xxxxxxxx',
                pass:'xxxxxxxxx'
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            }
        } );
        transport.verify(function (error, success) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('====>' + error);
            } else if (success) {
                console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please remove your passwords in the code before posting it to SO.

Comment: yes thank u ... any solution

Comment: Are you able to fix this problem? I'm facing exactly same error. Nothing helped me so far. Tried many stackoverflow suggestions.

Comment: Yes, the problem was fixed.
Since I was saying secure false there was no need to mention the auth attribute.
I have posted the Answer below. 

Even if the error is there then the port must be blocked. Either at internal or external Network

Answer (score 0):

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport( {
        debug: true,
        host: "smtp.xx.xxx.com",
        port: 25,
        secure: false,
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }
    } );
    transport.verify(function (error, success) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('====>' + error);
        } else if (success) {
            console.log("Server is ready to take our messages");
        }
    });
```